# Undeclared identifier error message

Tags: c++

I got an error message when calling `CreateThread` function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include <windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    DWORD TidA, TidB, TidC;
    HANDLE task1, task2, task3;

    task1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) Thread1, NULL, 0, &TidA);
    task2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) Thread2, NULL, 0, &TidB);
    task3 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) Thread3, NULL, 0, &TidC);

    SetThreadPriority(task1, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
    SetThreadPriority(task2, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
    SetThreadPriority(task3, THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST);

    CloseHandle(task1); 
    CloseHandle(task2); 
    CloseHandle(task3); 
}

void Thread1()
{
    printf("Task#2 >>> started\n");
    int *firstFunc = (new Functions())->firstFunc(Data::vectorInitialize(), Data::matrixInitialize(), Data::matrixInitialize());
    Sleep(3000);
    Data::vectorOutput(firstFunc);
    printf("\nTask#2 >>> finished\n");
}

void Thread2()
{
    printf("Task#1 >>> started\n");
    int **secondFunc = (new Functions())->secondFunc(Data::matrixInitialize(), Data::matrixInitialize(), Data::matrixInitialize(), Data::matrixInitialize());
    Sleep(2000);
    Data::matrixOutput(secondFunc);
    printf("\nTask#1 >>> finished\n");
}

void Thread3()
{
    printf("Task#3 >>> started\n");
    int *thirdFunc = (new Functions())->thirdFunction(Data::matrixInitialize(), Data::matrixInitialize(), Data::vectorInitialize());
    Sleep(1000);
    Data::vectorOutput(thirdFunc);
    printf("\nTask#3 >>> finished\n");
}
```

Here is error message:

```
 error C2065: Thread1: undeclared identifier
 error C2065: Thread2: undeclared identifier
 error C2065: Thread3: undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Move the functions above main, or forward declare them. (P.S: this has been asked many *many* times)

Comment: That's a compile-time error, not a run-time exception.

Comment: DO NOT CAST CALLBACKS. Give them the proper type instead. Better yet, use the standard threading library.

Answer (score 4):

Thread1 is used before it is defined.

you can move the Thread1, Thread2, Thread3 function definitions to above main

or you can declare it above main.

Answer (score 2):

You should forward declare the functions before `_tmain`:

```
void Thread1();
void Thread2();
void Thread3();
```